# How do I extract an HTML title with Perl?

Tags: html, perl, title

Is there a way to extract HTML page title using Perl?  I know it can be passed as a hidden variable during form submit and then retrieved in Perl that way but I was wondering if there is a way to do this without the submit?

Like, lets say i have an HTML page like this:

```
<html><head><title>TEST</title></head></html>
```

and then in Perl I want to do :

```
$q -> h1('something');
```

How can I replace 'something' dynamically with what is contained in <title> tags?

Comment: THe question is a bit confusing. You want to find out the title of the page? So, it would look more like: my $title = $q->h1(); right? Or do you want to set a new title?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use [pQuery](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?pQuery).  It works just like jQuery.

You can say:

```
use pQuery;
my $page = pQuery("http://google.com/");
my $title = $page->find('title');
say "The title is: ", $title->html;
```

Replacing stuff is similar:

```
$title->html('New Title');
say "The entirety of google.com with my new title is: ", $page->html;
```

You can pass an HTML string to the `pQuery` constructor, which it sounds like you want to do.

Finally, if you want to use arbitrary HTML as a "template", and then "refine" that with Perl commands, you want to use [Template::Refine](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Template::Refine).

Answer (score 3):

[HTML::HeadParser](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Parser) does this for you.

Comment: The link you posted returns search results that does not return HTML::HeadParser.  I had to look around for it:  http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser/

Comment: Ah, yes, the HTML::HeadParser module comes with HTML::Parser.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you are asking.  You seem to be talking about something that could run in the user's browser, or at least something that already has an html page loaded.

If that's *not* the case, the answer is [URI::Title](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/URI::Title).

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;

my $url = 'http://www.google.com'|| die "Specify URL on the cmd line";
my $html = get ($url);
$html =~ m{<TITLE>(.*?)</TITLE>}gism;

print "$1\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is wrong, if the HTML title tag is used more often then this can easily be overcome by checking to make sure that the title tag is valid (no tags in between).

```
my ($title) = $test_content =~ m/<title>([a-zA-Z\/][^>]+)<\/title>/si;
```

Answer (score 0):

## get the title name form the file.

```
                    my $spool = 0;

                    open my $fh, "<", $absPath or die $!; 
                    #open ($fh, "<$tempfile" );
                    # wrtie the opening brace
                    print WFL "[";
            while (<$fh>) {
                    # removes the new line from the line read
                        chomp;
                    # removes the leading and trailing spaces.
                    $_=~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
            # case where the <title> and </title> occures in one line
            # we print and exit in one instant
                if (($_=~/$startstring/i)&&($_=~/$endstring/i)) {

                        print WFL "'";

                    my ($title) = $_=~ m/$startstring(.+)$endstring/si;
                        print WFL "$title";
                        print WFL "',";
                        last;
                        }
            # case when the <title> is in one line and </title> is in other line

            #starting <title> string is found in the line
                elsif ($_=~/$startstring/i) {

                        print WFL "'";
            # extract everything after <title> but nothing before <title>       
                    my ($title) = $_=~ m/$startstring(.+)/si;
                        print WFL "$title";
                        $spool = 1;
                        }
            # ending string </title> is found
                elsif ($_=~/$endstring/i) {
            # read everything before </title> and nothing above that                                
                    my ($title) = $_=~ m/(.+)$endstring/si;
                        print WFL " ";
                        print WFL "$title";
                        print WFL "',";
                        $spool = 0;
                        last;
                        }
            # this will useful in reading all line between <title> and </title>
                elsif ($spool == 1) {
                        print WFL " ";
                        print WFL "$_";

                        }

                    }
        close $fh;
        # end of getting the title name
```

Answer (score -2):

If you just want to extract the page title you can use a regular expression. I believe that would be something like:

```
my ($title) = $html =~ m/<title>(.+)<\/title>/si;
```

where your HTML page is stored in the string `$html`. In `si`, the `s` stands for for *single line mode* (i.e., the dot also matches a newline) and `i` for *ignore case*.

Comment: Results will be not what what you want if there's another </title> on the page after the end of the actual title.

In general, regular expressions for HTML parsing is a limited proposition.