# pQuery cannot retrieve contents of webpage

Tags: perl

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574199/how-do-i-extract-an-html-title-with-perl) to retrieve a title from a URL.

As a simple example, I have the following code

```
use pQuery;
my $url = "http://google.com";
my $page = pQuery($url);
my $title = $page->find('title');
print $title->html;
```

but it does not print anything. Am I using it incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using it correctly, but [`pQuery`](http://metacpan.org/module/pQuery) has many problems. Its documentation says ***This module is still being written***, but the latest version 0.23 was released
 fourteen months ago

In this case, it is getting upset because it requires that an HTML document starts with `<html>` and ends with `</html>`, but the Google home page starts with a perfectly valid

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

The result is that it wraps the whole page in a pair of `<dummy>` ... `</dummy>` tags, which completely throws the HTML parser.

If you want to fetch the title of a web pages then I suggest you use the excellent [`Mojo::UserAgent`](http://metacpan.org/module/Mojo::UserAgent), like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use v5.10;

use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new->max_redirects(5);

my $url = 'https://www.google.co.uk/';

my $title = $ua->get($url)->res->dom->at('title')->text;

say qq{Title is: "$title"};
```

#### output

```
Title is: "Google"
```